# Animations are not being triggered on Scroll

Tags: javascript

I have called the animate.css and Wow.js in my theme.

```
//* Enqueue Animate.CSS and WOW.js
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_enqueue_scripts' );
function sk_enqueue_scripts() {


wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css' );


wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.min.js', array(), '', true );


}


//* Enqueue script to activate WOW.js
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_wow_init_in_footer');
function sk_wow_init_in_footer() {
add_action( 'print_footer_scripts', 'wow_init' );
}


//* Add JavaScript before </body>
function wow_init() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new WOW().init();
</script>
<?php }
```

Now Implemented it on the HTML using a text widget like this

```
<div class="wow bounceInUp">The image I have added here.</div>
```

But when I load my website and scroll down to the image, there is no animation triggered.

You can check it live at https://vashishthakapoor.com

I just want to know if I am doing everything right or not.

If I have done it right, why animations are not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have placed your CODE alright. Perhaps you need to **clear browser cache** to see the animation in action. In [your site](https://vashishthakapoor.com) I can see it's working.

> **Note:** Although your CODE will work, it's better to use it in the following manner if you have WordPress `4.5` or above:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_enqueue_scripts' );
function sk_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.min.js', array(), '', true );
    wp_add_inline_script( 'wow', 'new WOW().init();' );
}
```

**Why?**

1. The CODE is much smaller.
2. Using [`wp_add_inline_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) that way guarantees that the initialization call will run just after the required external `/js/wow.min.js` JavaScript file.